# Mezuzos on an "eruv"

Tags: halacha, minhag, mezuzah, eruv-chatzerot

What we colloquially call an "*eruv*" is actually intended to be a halachic doorway (*tzurath hapethach*) to count as a partition delineating a *reshuth hayachid* (private domain). As such, every post should really be obligated in a "*mezuza*" (see Chazon Ish Hilchos Mezuza 172; see also, however, Sefer Chovas haDar 5:1, both cited [here](http://dafyomi.co.il/discuss.php?gid=6&daf=11&file=4)). Leniencies are suggested where there is a threat that the mezuza scroll might be defaced by the public. Are there any Rabbis, communities (or private *eruvim*, for that matter) that do indeed put mezuzoth in the posts?

Answer (score 4):

We live in a *square* made up of 8 buildings with 4 entrances.

We have doorposts connected by a string at every entrance, as an Eruv.

When a neighbour - some 15 years ago - made a bris at home and invited **Reb Chaim Kanievsky שליט"א** to be Sandek, he noticed this.

**He paskened that we need a Mezuza at each entrance.**

<sup>As a result we replaced the string with a solid lintel. Why? 
1. Aligning a Mezuza under a string is next to impossible. 
2. Strings snap and then the Mezuzah has to be refastened; a pain when it's solidly affixed to prevent vandalism.</sup>

As to **why a regular Eruv does not have Mezuzot on every *entrance***, I've been told that these doorposts are not for *entering and exiting* and thus do not need a Mezuza.

See Kitzur Shulchan Aruch [סימן יא - הלכות מזוזה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0010_L2):

> אַךְ אִם יֵשׁ אֵיזֶה פֶתַח שֶׁאֵינוֹ עָשׂוּי אֶלָּא לְהַכְנִיס דֶּרֶךְ שָׁם אֵיזֶה מַשָּׂא לִפְרָקִים וְיֵשׁ שָׁם פֶּתַח אַחֵר לִכְנִיסָה וִיצִיאָה, אֲזַי הַפֶּתַח הֶעָשׂוּי רַק לְהַכְנִיס מַשָּׂאוֹת, פָּטוּר‏

Doors that are rarely used - e.g. for deliveries only - are exempt from Mezuza if there are other entrances that are usually used.

Comment: Do you check them every 25 years?

Comment: As in "שְׁתֵּי פְעָמִים בַּיּוֹבֵל"? I've been wondering if it's sensible to wait that long...

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen an *eruv* that didn't include at least some sections that are entered and exited. (It's probably worth pointing out that just because one doesn't notice the doorway, doesn't mean one hasn't entered/exited it.)

Comment: @Loewian, absolutely - and IIRC the fancier Eruvs have real doorways with doors that can actually block streets, and I suspect they have Mezuzoth; I'll keep an eye out for them and report back.